# An adjective for 'knowledge' starting with N

Tags: adjectives, synonyms

I'm looking for a word that embodies one of the following parameters:

Something that means the general sense of the following words—
Have, know, got, saved, stockpiled, possessed, acquired, reserved, 
accumulated, collected, and so on...

If that doesn't work, the fallback set could be an adjective that means lots, copious, plentiful, vast and so on.

Basically, I need this word to appear as an adjective to "knowledge" but it absolutely needs to start with N.

Any possibilities?

Comment: And no, it cannot be "nascent", for it needs to signify abundance, not scarcity.

Comment: Feel free to adjective-ify the following where they’re not already adjectives: ***[noetic](https://www.etymonline.com/word/noetic)***, ***[notion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/notion)***, ***[noesis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/noesis)***, ***[noegenesis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/noegenesis)***. The general root *noe-* or *noos-* might be productive in your hunt (it has a similar meaning to  *[gno-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/gnostic)*, which also starts with an `n` sound, but I like *gno* it it is also *spelled* with an initial `n`).

Comment: You might also consider ***[noosphere](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/noosphere)*** and ***[nootropic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nootropic)*** again from the same root. But if you’re looking for a word with some novel bite to it, especially for any kind of rationalist, transhumanist, or sci-fi context, IMO these two words are a bit hackneyed and played out.

Comment: a very tall order ... what collection of words did your search reveal?

Comment: If you're allowed a little poetic license, you might try _**'nlarged knowledge**_ or an _**'nlargemnet of knowledge**_.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center. It is going to be of extremely little use to any other visitors (unless it's a crossword solution, in which case it's off-topic per se).

Comment: You haven't "chosen" any answer. Please click on the checkmark or "tick" that appears below the bottom arrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tricky! Especially with the 'n'!

How about netted, nailed, or nobbled?

'Netted' has the sense of caught, as in catching fish, and it also suggests good fortune - that something went into your net. It can mean gain, acquire, have, got, and saved (as in 'rescued', with a net), stockpiled (loosely), possessed (if recently), accumulated in the sense of 'gained', collected. It doesn't mean lots, copious etc but it does loosely allude to that, describing as it does 'the act' of successfully acquiring - with one's 'net'.

'Nailed' has the sense of pinning down, making something specific. It can have a sense of learning or applying learning or knowledge well (colloquial) and of getting the exact answer: eg 'you nailed it, when you answered that question, John!'

Lastly 'nobbled' which I rather like, has a sense of 'acquire the good one' - to be lucky to 'get in there' and get the good one - for example 'I pushed to the front of the sale queue and nobbled this wonderful bargain!'

I know the word 'nobble' with that connotation, but you might not like that it does also mean gaining something by bribery and corruption as in 'he nobbled the jury by bribing them'.

The definitions online all seem to focus on this latter form of 'nobbling' as an heinous crime, talking about 'nobbling horses' in races etc. which surprised me, as I had always heard and used nobble colloquially in its milder form meaning more 'getting' or 'winning' something. For example: 'quick! nobble Mr. Brown before he goes off to lunch - and ask him for your payrise!' (In this case, we are definitely not doping Mr. Brown in order to have our way with him).

But, the aspect of the word that I like, for your purposes, is its meaning of 'grappling with something and winning it' eg 'the policeman did a flying tackle and nobbled the burglar'! This has the sense of have, got, acquire, stockpile, possess, that you want, in an 'n' word.

So... those are some possibilities!

Oh - and 'knit'. Meaning, join, comingle, merge, come together - not so far off from 'accumulated' or 'collected'.

https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=meaning+knit&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-sg&client=safari

Noble

How about 'noble'?

From your comments, that you want an acronym for your knowledge system: Share (or Spread) your -something- Knowledge - SYNK

~You want a word that implies value in the contributions given, don't you - so the veterans giving information feel honoured and want to contribute - hence - share or spread your 'noble' knowledge. But then everyone (else?) knows you also ('secretly') mean 'shit you need to know' hence making it valuable for the receiver of the knowledge, too. As well as being... funny

Comment: I quite like netted, its serves both "saved up" and "plentiful" to an extent. Nailed is a bit informal, and nobbled isn't common usage.

But I think you nailed it with netted! (pun intended. :P)

Comment: Thank-you @SujanSundareswaran ha ha! glad you liked it. You can click the up arrow and show you like my answer, if you want. What's it for, actually? Would be interesting to hear the sentence! Jelila 

Comment: I did, but I have only 14 reputation, which is 1 short of being able to publicly upvote. :)

Interesting story: We have just set up an internal wiki at our company, called SYNK. The official expansion for this acronym needs to be something like "Spread Your <insert the word here> Knowledge". But all our developers know that it really stands for "Shit You Need to Know".

Sssh! :)

Comment: Oh, I see! What about 'New'?  Share might be better than spread. Share Your New Knowledge.

Comment: It's a rather demented system that doesn't allow the asker to vote on his own answers! ☃️

Comment: "New" isn't quite apt because the wiki is mainly for company veterans to share their accumulated knowledge with the newer employees. So, it rather
 needs to be the opposite of 'new'. :)

Comment: how about Noble?

Comment: You want a word that implies value in the contributions given, don't you - so the veterans feel honoured and want to contribute - hence - share or spread your noble knowledge. But then everyone (else?) knows you also mean 'shit you need to know' hence making it valuable for the receiver of the knowledge, too. As well as being... funny

Comment: Oooh! Noble! I like it! I think that's what I'm gonna go with...thanks, Jelila!

(I can't mark a comment as an answer, right?)

Comment: Glad you like it! I will add it to my answer.

Comment: I don't remember if I upvoted the OPs question or not!! how would I know? And what effect would that have?  As my final answer to OP is given in a comment, to my own question, he is asking, how does he vote on that. And I said, I'd add it to my question body text... But maybe I don't need to?

Comment: "Noble" is the chosen one.

Comment: To notify a user you must use @ before their username e.g @Susan if you're on a home computer the site automatically completes the username for you. This doesn't happen on mobiles...☹ As the author, you will always know if someone posts a comments. You should visit the help centre and begin learning the ropes, the system will then begin to make sense.

Comment: Might be a good idea to delete the trail of comments, but up to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps,

**nourishing** or **nutritious**

Comment: Interesting, but they don't quite signify "stockpiled" or "abundance".

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky! What about a creative use of the prefix "non"? So nonmyopic, nonlimited, etc. Or some more spiritual choices: nirvanic, nitid (Bright, luminious), or novalike.

Comment: The non-prefixed one have a bit of a negative connotation, don't you think? And the other three words are a bit of a stretch...but I like nitid, thanks for teaching me that one! :)

Comment: Great idea about 'non'. And nitid - never heard that! Great word!